# The Other Image Map Resolution doesn't work properly

Tags: html

I have an image map with clickable areas I implemented it by using  and  tags The problem is other screen resolution doesn't work.

I have an image map with clickable areas
I implemented it using  and 
The problem is that it's not responsive and other screen resolution doesn't work or I'm reducing the app
Because the pixel numbers change
Thanks

```
<img src="workplace.jpg" alt="Workplace" usemap="#workmap">
<map name="workmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="34,44,270,350" alt="Computer" href="computer.htm">
  <area shape="rect" coords="290,172,333,250" alt="Phone" href="phone.htm">
  <area shape="circle" coords="337,300,44" alt="Coffee" href="coffee.htm">
</map>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need a plugin for that:
https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/image-map-resizer